# Inconsistency between test and django: :int() argument must be a string but also TypeError: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, pytest

I have an API view that receives a request and creates some data. It works fine. When I am running my test I wrote with pytest I receive this error:

```
 node_name = (data_node['name'])
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

When I change my code to be an integer like this: `node_name = int((data_node['name']))` my django view gives me this error:

`:int() argument must be a string`

And I am like... whuat?!

This is my view (shortened for brevity):

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def CreateGraphView(request):
    """Receives a request in the following format: {'project': 'project1', 'name': 'Graph1', 'description': 'test', 
        'nodes': [{'name': '25', 'graph': 3}, {'name': '24', 'graph': 3}], 
        'edges': [{'name': 'EdgeForGraph1', 'graph': 3, 'source': '25', 'target': '25'}]}
"""

    nodes = request.data['nodes']

    for data_node in nodes:
        print(type(data_node))
        node_name = (data_node['name'])
        print(node_name)
        print(type(node_name))
        new_node = Node.objects.create(name=node_name)


    status_code = HttpResponse.status_code
    return Response(status_code)
```

The data (request) I am sending looks like this:

```
 {'project': 'project1', 'name': 'Graph1', 'description': 'test', 
        'nodes': [{'name': '25', 'graph': 3}, {'name': '24', 'graph': 3}], 
        'edges': [{'name': 'EdgeForGraph1', 'graph': 3, 'source': '25', 'target': '25'}]}
```

And finally, if it helps my test (I send the same data):

```
  def test_aut_user_can_create_graph(self, client):
        data = data
        url = api_reverse('nameofurl')
        response = client.post(url, data)
        assert response.status_code == 201
```

I am very confused why my test wouldn't accept the code and my code wouldn't accept my test. Especially because when debugging and printing out the type of data_node it tells me it is a dict. So that should be correct.

Can someone help me out on this? Would be very much appreciated. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What's `nodes` in your view ? it's not a method argument.

Comment: My apologies. I left that out by accident. Question is updated with ```nodes```. Basically nodes is the data I receive as a request. Request is a list of dictionaries. So I am looping through the list and for every node_data (which should be a dict) I am doing the stuff in the loop

Comment: Perhaps the two errors are coming from different places in the data?  Sounds like you've got one place where the value is a dict, but the `name` entry is mistakenly a string, and another place where the value is mistakenly a string.

Comment: thank you Linovia and jasonharper for your help. Daniels answer did the trick

Comment: whoever downvotes me please let me know why....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the issue is that you have not told the test client that the data is JSON, so DRF does not know to deserialize it and is just treating it as a string. Try this:

```
response = client.post(url, data, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: omg yes that was exactly it!! Thank you so much Daniel! Really appreciate it!!